# Taylor expansion of the solutions of the equation $1-4 \cos(\frac{1}{x})+8x \sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In following [article](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-whose-derivative-at-0-is-one-but-which-is-not-increasing-near-0/), I give an example of a function whose derivative at 0 is equal to 1 but which is not increasing near 0. The function is:
$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & \mathbb{R} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
    & 0 & \longmapsto & 0 \\
    & x & \longmapsto & x + 4x^2 \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} \text{ for } x \neq 0 \end{array}$$

For all $x \neq 0$ we have:
$$f^\prime(x)=1-4 \cos{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}+8x \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

According to [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) and the article I mention, $f$ vanishes at least twice on each interval $(2n\pi,2(n+1)\pi)$ for $n \ge 1$ integer. Is there a simple way to compute an approximation of those solutions $u_n,v_n$ in the form $u_n=A(n)+a_1/n+a_2/n^2+\dots+a_p/n^p+o(1/n^{p+1})$ where $A(n)$ is a "simple function"? Can SAGE do that easily?

Comment: What do you mean by "a Taylor expansion of those solutions"?

Comment: Note $g(x)=x+x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ is like your $f$ near $0$ but is wilder. And it may be computationally simpler: We get $g'(1/\sqrt {\pi n}) = 1+2(-1)^n\sqrt {\pi n},$ which shows (by Darboux) that $g'$ takes every value in $\mathbb {R}$ in every neighborhood of $0.$